# EmberJS Nested Models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have what I think is a fairly normal JSON response:

```
"data": {
  .....
  "user": {
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe"
  }
  ....
}
```

And then a model "app/models/data.js":

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  ....
  user: DS.belongsTo("user"),
  ....
});
```

with the user model "app/models/user.js":

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  surname: DS.attr()
});
```

The page refuses to load. If I remove the `user` line from the `data` model, it works (but then obviously doesn't have the user info).

What is going wrong? Looking through all the other StackOverflow questions, I believe it's because it is looking for an ID in the `users` model, but that doesn't exist. The JSON response I get is exactly as above - it's not loaded and populated into that response.

I'm using Ember v 1.13.2 and Ember-Data v 1.13.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your record doesn't have an ID then it's not a record, it's what Ember Data considers an 'embedded record'. You can't treat it the same way as a normal record. Ember Data does have a way to deal with this, which you can read about [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html).

Comment: Also, since I started using Ember 2 years ago, embedded records have been one of the biggest pain points for Ember Data. I don't know what the current state is (as I don't use Ember Data any more), but it used to be easier to just avoid them all together. If they turn out to be a pain, you might want to consider giving it an ID and just [sideloading](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships) the data.

Comment: I thought it had something to do with not having ID's. I'm not having luck with the EmbeddedRecordsMixin either. I added the following to my RESTSerializer:

`attrs: {
    user: {embedded: 'always'},
  },`

Comment: I'm not really the guy to ask about embedded records (as I said, they've always been a pain point). I just know that if you want to have nested objects, you'll need embedded records (or a custom attribute type if you don't mind changing how you're currently doing things). If you're having problems with embedded records, you might want to ask another question with more specifics.

Comment: Ok, this seems impossible with Ember Data. What are you using? Assuming you have nested records in your responses...

Comment: I'm using a library I wrote, Ember Graph, but it doesn't have support for embedded records like you want. What I do is write a custom attribute type to serialize/deserialize the objects. But that means that you lose all of the niceties that come with models. You can read about custom attribute types (transforms) [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Transform.html).